# How to make a Azure SQL Exec or select another table/procedure in another Azure SQL

Tags: azure-sql-database, azure-sql-server

I've two Azure SQL Servers, each one contains one database, I need to exec Selects or Stored procedures between them.

For example:

Server1.database.windows.net DB: local1
Server2.database.windows.net DB: remote1

in Server1: `Select * from Server2.remote1.dbo.Orders` and this query return a list of orders.

in Server2: `Exec Server1.local1.dbo.ProcedureOrders` and this execute a stored procedure in Server1

First of all, is this possible? If yes, how?

Comment: If my answer is helpful for you, hope you can  mark it as answer. This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. Azure sql database doesn't support linked server, but like @Alberto Morillo mentioned that [Elastic Query](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-elastic-query-overview) can help you query and execute stored procedure in other SQL Server.

For the remote table query, here are the steps:

1. **Create database scoped master key and credentials:**

   `CREATE MASTER KEY ENCRYPTION BY PASSWORD = 'master_key_password'; CREATE DATABASE SCOPED CREDENTIAL <credential_name>  WITH IDENTITY = '<username>',   SECRET = '<password>' [;]`
2. **Create external data sources:**

   `<External_Data_Source> ::= CREATE EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE <data_source_name> WITH  (TYPE = RDBMS, LOCATION = ’<fully_qualified_server_name>’, DATABASE_NAME = ‘<remote_database_name>’,   CREDENTIAL = <credential_name>  ) [;]`
3. **External Tables:**

   `CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE [ database_name . [ schema_name ] . | schema_name . ] table_name   ( { <column_definition> } [ ,...n ])      { WITH ( <rdbms_external_table_options> ) }  )[;]`

   `<rdbms_external_table_options> ::=  DATA_SOURCE = <External_Data_Source>,  [ SCHEMA_NAME = N'nonescaped_schema_name',]  [ OBJECT_NAME = N'nonescaped_object_name',]`

For execute remote stored procedure:

Elastic query also introduces a stored procedure that provides direct access to the remote database. The stored procedure is called `sp_execute _remote` and can be used to execute remote stored procedures or T-SQL code on the remote database.

Example:

```
EXEC sp_execute_remote
        N'MyExtSrc',
        N'select count(w_id) as foo from warehouse'
```

For more details, please reference:

1. [Reporting across scaled-out cloud databases (preview)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-elastic-query-horizontal-partitioning)
2. [Query across cloud databases with different schemas (preview)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-elastic-query-vertical-partitioning)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you for the high-explaning response!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [elastic queries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-elastic-query-overview) to query tables across different databases in different logical servers and even when they belong to different subscriptions. You can find and example [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/256710/elastic-queries-across-subscriptions-in-azure-sql).

You can also run transactions across databases on different logical servers as announced in [this](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/elastic-database-transactions-general-availability/) article.